# Reversing a List leads to Seg fault

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, struct

I'm trying to reverse a Linked list recursively. I have these structs:

```
typedef Test test;

typedef struct Node {
    test t;
    struct Node *nxt;
} LNode;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    LNode *first;
} L;
```

Where Test is a struct containing a student name and grade (Grade on a Test).

```
void recursiveReverse(L * r) {
       LNode * first;
       first = r->first; //first node in list

       reverseList(first);
}

void reverseList(LNode * first) {
    LNode * rest;
    rest = first->nxt;

    reverseList(r,rest);

    first->nxt->nxt = first;
    first->nxt = NULL;

    first = rest;
}
```

However, I seem to be getting a segfault when attempting this. I'm not allowed to change the parameters arguments for the function `recursiveReverse`, I'm told that I have to call another function, and use that one as the recursive calling function (Which I have). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How does the recursion end?

Comment: Start by finding the shortest list (which will be either 2 or 3 items) that causes the problem.   Then step through the code with a debugger to see whats going wrong.

Comment: It is not entirely clear why your reverseList needs the `r` parameter. It is also not clear how exactly you have tried to follow the linked algorithm. Your current program bears no resemblance to it.

Comment: I realize that parameter is not needed now, as for it bearing resemblance to it, I've removed the link as I thought it was similar, I guess not.

Comment: What is the point of defining a `struct` with only one member?

Comment: Forgot to enter the other field, sorry.

Comment: Perhaps you do want to study that program some more. It teaches you a couple of important concepts: how to terminate recursion, and how to return results of a computation from a function.

Comment: So effectively your saying, to not use a void function, but a function of type struct, with a return value, would that fix my problem?

Comment: This code won't compile. Please provide a version that compiles. (e.g. `reverseList(r,rest);` but `r` is not defined)

Comment: This is very linear, too big a list and you'll get a stack overflow error. I think you should consider other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important rule of writing recursive functions is that they must terminate. In simple terms, there must be a condition under which the recursive function does *not* call itself. This is so-called "base case".

For your list reversal function the base case is when the portion of the list that you must reverse contains exactly one node, because a single-node list is a trivial reverse of itself. Therefore, there needs to be a case inside `reverseList` where you say something like this:

```
if (first->nxt == NULL) {
    // Do not go into recursive invocation
    return; // This is not complete yet
}
```

Another thing that is missing from your code is that the reversed list will have a new head, which is the node that used to be the tail. Your `reverseList` should return it.

A useful trick to writing the rest of the recursive function is to imagine that the function is already written for you, and call it with the knowledge of *what* it does, forgetting for a moment of *how* it does it. In case of list reversal the recursive step is relatively easy: you obtain the head of the reversed list, and then change the next of the current node to point back to the current node.

```
LNode* reverseList(LNode* list) {
    if (list->nxt == null) {
        return list;
    }
    // Reverse the tail
    LNode *head = reverseList(list->nxt);
    // Invert this node
    list->nxt->nxt = list;
    // Return the result of tail reversal
    return head;
}
```

The only thing missing at this point is setting the new tail's `nxt` to `NULL`. You should do it inside your `recursiveReverse` function:

```
void recursiveReverse(L * r) {
    LNode *first = r->first;
    LNode *newHead = reverseList(first);
    first->nxt = NULL;
    r->first = newHead;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/cDKvuI)

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't head call Reverse List, not Reverse?

Comment: Also I still seem to segfault with this implementation

Comment: @user3739406 Yes, it needs to be `reverseList`, not `reverse`. I fixed that. It is strange that you are seeing segfaults with this implementation. Were you able to follow the implementation in the demo? Also make sure that you are constructing your list correctly.